# Crm 2011 - Page is still "dirty" after manually saving

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

On my function I'm checking if there are any changes on the page, and if there are I'm saving them.
However, even after saving `Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty()` is still `true`:

```js
  var isPageDirty = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty(); //true
  if (isPageDirty) { //Save if there were any changes
      Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
  }
  isPageDirty = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getIsDirty(); //still true!
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `isPageDirty` change to `false` after saving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be some other piece of script setting a value on that form. You can check what field/fields are causing this - by simply looping through the attributes, for example:

```
function showDirtyAttributes(){
    var names = "";
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute, index) {
        if (attribute.getIsDirty()) {
            names += attribute.getName() + ";";
        }
    });
    alert(names);
}
```

Taken from [here](http://gotchahunter.net/2012/11/dynamics-crm-get-all-updated-fields-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to tell which fields are dirty is to alert the entity data xml  i.e.

```
alert(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getDataXml())
```